# Querydsl :org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableExceptionand com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:

Tags: json, spring, jackson, querydsl, many-to-one

I am using Querydsl (4.1.1) for implementing search filter. I want to know how to select specific column in Querydsl.
I tried to select specific column using Querydsl select clause. But  I am getting following exception.

**AccountController**

```
public List<String> seach() {

        return accService.Search();
    }
```

**AccountSercice**

```
public List<String> Search() {  
    QAccount account = QAccount.account;
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
             query.select(account.sclientacctid, account.sacctdesc).from(account);
    return query.fetch();
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.querydsl.core.types.QTuple$TupleImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the *select* to filter out the column:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
QAccountModel accountModel = QAccountModel.accountModel;
List<Tuple> result = query.select(accountModel.sacctdesc).from(accountModel).fetch();
for (Tuple row : result) {
 System.out.println("sacctdesc " + row.get(accountModel.sacctdesc));
}
```

Or via native query:

```
//example with native query
HibernateSQLQuery query = new HibernateSQLQuery(session, templates);
List<String> names = query.from(cat).list(cat.name);
```

Comment: I tried this.I am getting this exception org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON:

Comment: This is a problem in the controller level not in the query itself, please add the log wit the stack trace and the code involved

Comment: I added code and error log.  In the above code if i am  selecting only one parameter like this query.select(account.sclientacctid) I am getting result But that result not in json format and one more thing when i am adding second parameter I am getting above error

Comment: i've updated the answer, adding the select part return the selected columns inside a Tuple and not directly to the raw type unless you use the native version

Comment: what is templates

Comment: you can find additional information here: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch03s02.html

Comment: using this List<String>  data in array format. not in json(key value)